# Non-essential travel to USA

Tags: usa, canada, covid-19

I'm a Canadian permanent resident and Italian citizen wanting to go to the USA for non-essential purposes. I have both doses of the COVID-19 vaccine. My understanding is that I will be able to travel, but only by plane, and I will have to provide a negative test upon entering the USA and entering Canada.

Is my understanding correct? Where can I find an accurate source of information? I checked this page https://ca.usembassy.gov/travel-restrictions-fact-sheet/ but it was last updated on March 2021..